# SharePoint & jQuery hide error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

How I can hide div witch contains text? I have to hide SharePoint error message.
I found this blog: http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/227/comment-page-1

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:contains('Error')").hide();
    $("div:contains('Access denied'):not(:has(div))").hide();
});
```

but it's not working... Why?

**I tried this:**

```
$( "div:contains('Access')" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

and this:

```
$( "div:contains('Access')" ).css( "visibility", "hidden" );
```

but those broke the site.

because I have subsite same problem, I add jQuery to master page. And I don't know divs name, because first site it's named WPQ1 and other site it's WPQ4. So, my only change if find div which contains specific text.

I was thinking, how I can use this, if I don't know divs name?

```
.replace("Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.", "");
```

How I can hide error message div?
I use: jquery-1.10.1.min.js

Comment: Use your F12 developer tools first and paste `$("div:contains('Access')")` into the console. Then make sure that an element is returned so that you can proof that your selector actually works.

Comment: So your final requirement is that the div containing  some specific text should be hidden ?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
      Error Msg 1:<div>Error 404!, Access denied </div><br/>

      Error Msg 2:<div>Unauthorised  Access Denied1 </div><br/>

      Error Msg 3:<div> Access to user Denied </div><br/>

      <input id="btn" type="button"  value="Error Check" />
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
     $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        $('div:contains("Access denied")').hide();
     });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/x56HA/10/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't work, it broke site also,  but I solved problem: $("div:contains('Access')").css("color", "transparent");

Comment: If you guys know better way solve this, I like the heard it =)

Comment: @user3172297: the code what i posted was clean , why did it brake your site ? the only change i could see is that, instead of hiding your making the css transparent. btw what more are you expecting ?

Comment: Ye, I know that your code works, however SharePoint causes problem. If I try hide that div, it hides all content on SharePoint site. I don't know why. I know that my solution is also very bad, but its only working solution right now...

Comment: @user3172297: if thats the issue , then you can try one more work around, instead of setting a transparent color, just extract the content of the targert div and save it in an Object like this, `var obj=new Object();obj[<index as div id>]=<content of div>;`,then remove that div from the dom structure. if anytime same error msg div needs to be shown, then construct one with the content/msg saved in the `Object()`. this way you will be able to achieve the same thing what `.hide()` would have :) hope that helps